# Get declared values in function in PHP

Tags: php

This is about RAW php coding. I have a page - "config.php" and there are some declarations here.

**//config.php**

```
<?php
$myvalue = "This is a test";
include("functions.php");
?>
```

**//functions.php**

```
<?php
function testFunction()
{
   $dd = $myvalue;
   echo $dd;
}
?>
```

And when I call **"testFunction()"** from another page like **"page.php"** I want it to echo **"This is a test"**. How can I do this? **"config.php"** is included to **"page.php"**. Hope the scenario  is understandable.

**//page.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
testFunction();
?>
```

Comment: if you want to check if your function exists/defined you can use [function_exists](http://php.net/function_defined) like `<?php echo function_exists('testFunction') ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line of your function, add:

```
global $myvalue;
```

Your `$myvalue`-variable is transfered into `functions.php` when you include that php-file after declaring the variable, but you have to tell your function to use this **global**  variable.

Your function would look like this:

```
function testFunction()
{
   global $myvalue;
   $dd = $myvalue;
   echo $dd;
}
```

Comment: How can you say the variable is not function specific?

Comment: Not academically the right words; just trying to explain how this is a global variable as opposed to a local variable within the function (hence the "function specific"-term). Now removing that parenthesis...

Comment: Well the other suggestion is to make it a local variable by using a function parameter and the calling the function appropriately.

Comment: @hakre I know, see comment on your post.

Answer (score 2):

What you're colliding with is [PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Variables (`$foo`) are only accessible  outside or inside the `function()` declaration (but do not cross this boundary unless you use the [`global`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) modifier). However, [constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) can be seen throughout.

Example:

```
<?php
  $foo = 'bar';
  define('CONST_FOO', 'bar');

  echo $foo;      // output: bar
  echo CONST_FOO; // output: bar

  function Foo(){
    echo $foo;      // undefined, out of scope
    echo CONST_FOO; // output: bar
  }
  function Bar(){
    global $foo; // now $foo can be seen

    echo $foo;      // output: bar
    echo CONST_FOO; // output: bar
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the parameters a function uses *with* the function:

*functions.php*:

```
<?php
function testFunction($value)
{
   echo $value;
}
?>
```

Then in *page.php*:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
testFunction($myvalue);
?>
```

This will make your code more modular.

See as well: [Is include()/require() with “side effects” a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697389/is-include-require-with-side-effects-a-bad-practice/7697490)

Comment: I agree passing variables as arguments is generally a much better solution (though that was not strictly what was asked here). Upvote for useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$myValue` is global, and by default cannot be seen from within the function scope. You could explicitly make it available like this:

```
<?php
function testFunction()
{
    global $myValue;
    $dd = $myvalue;
    echo $dd;
}
```

Or you could define a constant:

```
<?php
define ('MY_VALUE', 'This is a test');

// functions.php
function testFunction()
{
    $dd = MY_VALUE;
    echo $dd;
}
```

Or you could make it a static or const member of a config class:

```
<?php
// config.php
class Config {
    public static $myValue = 'This is a test';
    const myConst = 'This is a test';
}

// functions.php
require_once 'config.php';
function testFunction()
{
    $dd = Config::$myValue;
    echo $dd;

    $dd = Config::myConst;
    echo $dd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare that myValue is global, or use the $_GLOBALS array like this:

```
<?php
function testFunction()
{
   $dd = $_GLOBALS['myvalue'];
   echo $dd;
}
?>
```

Comment: Though it's an _option_, I advise against using globals as so many things can go wrong. Also, it may just be verbiage, but "must" wouldn't be an accurate statement.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it? :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

... and of course declare global variable