# Include file and suppressing side effects

Tags: php, scope

Imagine I have two php scripts `script.php` and `inc.php`. (`<?php` omitted)

**inc.php**:

```
$foo = 'a';
```

**script.php**:

```
$foo = 'b'; // $foo is b
include 'inc.php'; // $foo is a
```

Then in the moment that `inc.php` is included the variable `$foo` is overwritten with `'a'`. I'd like to have files that can be included without side effect.

The most practical would be a sort of local scope:

**inc.php (2)**:

```
// $foo is b
{
    $foo = 'a'; // $foo is a
} // $foo is b
```

By my knowledge no such construct exists, the only thing I could think of was something like:

**inc.php (3)**:

```
// $foo is b
call_user_func(function() {
    $foo = 'a'; // $foo is a
}); // $foo is b
```

1. Are there other (better / more elegant) ways to make a file safe for inclusion?
2. Is there a way I can safely include `inc.php` into `script.php` if `inc.php` cannot be modified?

Comment: why not [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) ?

Comment: the password should be in a configuration file and not within the source code. same for the DSN string and the username. you're most likely missing basic concepts. If you construct this scenario, please create a new example from scratch with as little code as necessary to show your issue (e.g. I can imagine this does not need two files, a 10 line script (if even) should be enough to make your point.

Comment: @hakre I adapted the example to focus on the issue at hand.

Comment: @JohnnyJS I thought variables were unaffected by namespaces?

Comment: @Samuel: Why multiple files? This does not need necessary for the minimum example. Please turn this into a more clean and easier to reproduce example(s).

Comment: you can return value within the required file. Like `$foo = require('somefile.php');` and in somefile.php `return 'wow';`

Comment: @hakre The point of my question is about (1) how to make a file that can be included safely, and (2) how do I include a file without allowing it to override local variables in the file including it.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I didn't know that, interesting, the required file will still have side affects though in terms of overriding local variables right?

Comment: @Samuel: You might be looking for a function like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7697490/367456

Comment: @hakre That looks like it might address this problem :)

Comment: @hakre Would you consider applying that answer to this question? Then I can accept it

Comment: well, re-reading the question I find it hard to word an answer with that function quickly and I also don't like to copy that answer over verbatim. Are you okay that I close-vote against the other question as duplicate instead? That would mark it "resolved" and it also links to the existing answer. ok?

Comment: @hakre Sure, it just bothers me as an unanswered, down voted question where the right answer is hidden in the comment section!

Comment: @Samuel: The close vote changes nothing about the voting (up/down) however, it's marked as solved in the sense that a new answer can't be given any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Set constants:

```
defined('PASSWORD') or define('PASSWORD', 'value');
```

Constants are global but cannot do defined 2 times.
If you define PASSWORD constant in "db.php" then cannot to be redefined in PASSWORD in "script.php".

Comment: I adapted the example to focus more on the issue. I'm specifically interested in the case where variables are used and to make a file safe or include it safely.